# API GitLab'a поломано?

Tags: gitlab

Необходимо с помощью АПИ GitLab'a посмотреть кто какую строку редактировал
У них есть [blame](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-file-blame-from-repository)
Но как я не пытался, всегда возвращается 404 not founded
При этом [raw](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-raw-file-from-repository) работает как и следует

Вроде я [не один](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/cant-get-blame-from-the-gitlab-api/32527) такой

Есть ли какое то решение этой проблемы? Или есть ли какой то другой способ?

Comment: Вы даже не показали, как пытались-то

Comment: Но а если даже на форуме гитлаба никто ничего не ответил, то и тут тем более вряд ли помогут

Answer (score 1):

Все работает для такого тестого запроса

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/384627/repository/files/Languages%2fLang_ru.wixproj/blame?ref=master
```

Судя по ошибке, ваш запрос составлен не верно.

Возможно, использованы недопустимые символы. В полном имени файла символ `/` должен быть заменен на `%2f`. В примере `Languages/Lang_ru.wixproj` заменен на `Languages%2fLang_ru.wixproj`.

Обращаю внимание, что в конце следует передать ветку `ref=master`.